# For loop won't append to list

Tags: python, list, append

I'm trying to make a for-loop that takes in a list and appends different strings based on the content. This is what I have:

```
for person in hugelist:
    if person[4]=="[b]" and person[5]=="[b]" in person:
        person.append("tn")
    elif person[4] == "[b]" and person[5]== "[n]" in person:
        person.append("fp")
    elif person[4] == "[n]" and person[5]== "[b]" in person:
        person.append("fn")
    elif person[4] == "[n]" and person[5] == "[n]" in person:
        person.append("tp")
    else:
        person.append("N/A")
```

All it does is append `N/A` to all lists, if I disable the last else, it doesn't append anything at all. What am I doing wrong?

Sample text of the file I'm working with:

```
 [['1', 'R2_3_3_2_0Y0.pct', '1355', '[n]', '[n]', '0'],
 ['2', 'R3_4_3_2_90Y150.pct', '2079', '[n]', '[n]', '150'],
 ['3', '2_4_4_2_0Y150.pct', '1834', '[b]', '[b]', '150'],
 ['4', '3_3_3_2_0Y100.pct', '4780', '[b]', '[b]', '100'],
 ['5', '3_3_3_3_90Y50.pct', '1685', '[b]', '[b]', '50'],
 ['6', 'R2_4_4_2_0Y50.pct', '1237', '[n]', '[n]', '50']]
```

I want it to add `"tn"` to the list with `[b], [b]` and so on.

Comment: `person[5]=="b" in person` is checking if either `True` or `False` is in `person`.

Comment: Please show us a sample content of person!

Comment: Don't paste it here, edit your question to show a small part of it with correct formatting. We can't read that.

Comment: I believe your indices are off by one, change to `person[3]` and `person[4]`

Comment: person[3] and person[4] I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists use indices that start at index 0.

```
random_list=['0_index','1_index','2_index']
```

If you change your indices in your `if..elif` and remove `in person` then it'll work.

```
hugelist=[['1', 'R2_3_3_2_0Y0.pct', '1355', '[n]', '[n]', '0'],
 ['2', 'R3_4_3_2_90Y150.pct', '2079', '[n]', '[n]', '150'],
 ['3', '2_4_4_2_0Y150.pct', '1834', '[b]', '[b]', '150'],
 ['4', '3_3_3_2_0Y100.pct', '4780', '[b]', '[b]', '100'],
 ['5', '3_3_3_3_90Y50.pct', '1685', '[b]', '[b]', '50'],
 ['6', 'R2_4_4_2_0Y50.pct', '1237', '[n]', '[n]', '50']]

for person in hugelist:
    if person[3]=="[b]" and person[4]=="[b]":
        person.append("tn")
    elif person[3] == "[b]" and person[4]== "[n]":
        person.append("fp")
    elif person[3] == "[n]" and person[4]== "[b]":
        person.append("fn")
    elif person[3] == "[n]" and person[4] == "[n]":
        person.append("tp")
    else:
        person.append("N/A")
```

`hugelist` will become:

```
[['1', 'R2_3_3_2_0Y0.pct', '1355', '[n]', '[n]', '0', 'tp'],
['2', 'R3_4_3_2_90Y150.pct', '2079', '[n]', '[n]', '150', 'tp'],
['3', '2_4_4_2_0Y150.pct', '1834', '[b]', '[b]', '150', 'tn'],
['4', '3_3_3_2_0Y100.pct', '4780', '[b]', '[b]', '100', 'tn'],
['5', '3_3_3_3_90Y50.pct', '1685', '[b]', '[b]', '50', 'tn'],
['6', 'R2_4_4_2_0Y50.pct', '1237', '[n]', '[n]', '50', 'tp']]
```

Comment: That seems like it should work, but now when I try to run it, it says string index out of range?

Comment: I'm not sure what was different, but I copied your code and now it works! Thank you so much, I've been stuck with that one for ages!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the index of a list begins with `0`.

```
hugelist =  [['1', 'R2_3_3_2_0Y0.pct', '1355', '[n]', '[n]', '0'],
             ['2', 'R3_4_3_2_90Y150.pct', '2079', '[n]', '[n]', '150'],
             ['3', '2_4_4_2_0Y150.pct', '1834', '[b]', '[b]', '150'],
             ['4', '3_3_3_2_0Y100.pct', '4780', '[b]', '[b]', '100'],
             ['5', '3_3_3_3_90Y50.pct', '1685', '[b]', '[b]', '50'],
             ['6', 'R2_4_4_2_0Y50.pct', '1237', '[n]', '[n]', '50']]

for person in hugelist:
    if person[3]=="[b]" and person[4]=="[b]":
        person.append("tn")
    elif person[3] == "[b]" and person[4]== "[n]":
        person.append("fp")
    elif person[3] == "[n]" and person[4]== "[b]":
        person.append("fn")
    elif person[3] == "[n]" and person[4] == "[n]":
        person.append("tp")
    else:
        person.append("N/A")

print(hugelist)
```

which outputs,

```
[['1', 'R2_3_3_2_0Y0.pct', '1355', '[n]', '[n]', '0', 'tp'], 
['2', 'R3_4_3_2_90Y150.pct', '2079', '[n]', '[n]', '150', 'tp'], 
['3', '2_4_4_2_0Y150.pct', '1834', '[b]', '[b]', '150', 'tn'], 
['4', '3_3_3_2_0Y100.pct', '4780', '[b]', '[b]', '100', 'tn'], 
['5', '3_3_3_3_90Y50.pct', '1685', '[b]', '[b]', '50', 'tn'], 
['6', 'R2_4_4_2_0Y50.pct', '1237', '[n]', '[n]', '50', 'tp']]
```

Comment: `I want it to add "tn" to the list with [b], [b] and so on.`?

Comment: @depperm, sorry for misunderstanding. How about now? I've just updated my answer.